# Combine two result sets into one in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, sql, join, group-by

[Fiddle Example 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc11d/18)

[Fiddle Example 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e6483/1)

Can anyone please tell me if it's possible to combine the following two result sets into one in order not to use two separate queries?

```
PRODUCT_PAGE_ID PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME   SIMILAR_PRODUCT SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID  RESULT
22              Nokia 8234          E821            777                 2
22              Nokia 8234          HTC 2811        444                 2


PRODUCT_PAGE_ID PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME   VOTER_NAME  COMMENT
22              Nokia 8234          John        blahblahblah
22              Nokia 8234          David       xxxxxxxxxxxx
22              Nokia 8234          Peter       yyyyyyyyyyyy
22              Nokia 8234          John        zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

My expected outcome should be:

```
PRODUCT_PAGE_ID   PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME  SIMILAR_PRODUCT  SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID    RESULT VOTER_NAME COMMENT
    22              Nokia 8234       E821             777                   2      NULL       NULL
    22              Nokia 8234       HTC 2811         444                   2      NULL       NULL
    22              Nokia 8234       NULL             NULL                  NULL   John       blahblahblah
    22              Nokia 8234       NULL             NULL                  NULL   David      xxxxxxxxxxxx
    22              Nokia 8234       NULL             NULL                  NULL   Peter      yyyyyyyyyyyy
    22              Nokia 8234       NULL             NULL                  NULL   John       zzzzzzzzzzzz
```

The first result set uses this query,

```
SELECT p.product_page_id,p.name AS product_page,
       p2.name AS similar_product,
       p2.product_page_id AS similar_product_id,COUNT(poll.choice) AS result
FROM poll 
INNER JOIN product p ON poll.product_page_id = p.product_page_id
INNER JOIN product p2 ON poll.choice = p2.product_page_id
WHERE poll.product_page_id = 22
GROUP BY poll.choice
ORDER BY result DESC
```

While the second one uses

```
SELECT pc.product_page_id,p.name AS product_page_name,
       u.name AS voter_name,pc.comment
FROM `poll_comment` pc INNER JOIN `user` u 
ON u.user_id = pc.user_id
INNER JOIN `product` p ON pc.product_page_id = p.product_page_id 
WHERE pc.product_page_id = 22
LIMIT 10;
```

I have a poll that allows users to vote for any suggested products similar to the product they are browsing. They are allowed to vote multiple items at a time and leave a comment. Each voted item uses a single row inserted into table `poll`. I'm trying to pull the vote counts as well as 10 comments from the voters in one single query. The problem is that the query that I have come up with is not able to get the correct vote counts or the comments on the product.

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE poll
    (`user_id` int,`product_page_id`int,`choice` int)
;

INSERT INTO poll
    (`user_id`,`product_page_id`,`choice`)
VALUES
    (1,22,444),
    (1,22,777),
    (2,22,444),
    (3,22,777)

;
CREATE TABLE poll_comment
    (`user_id` int,`product_page_id`int,`comment` varchar(40))
;

INSERT INTO poll_comment
    (`user_id`,`product_page_id`,`comment`)
VALUES
    (1,22,'blahblahblah'),
    (2,22,'xxxxxxxxxxxx'),
    (3,22,'yyyyyyyyyyyy'),
    (1,33,'zzzzzzzzzzzz'),
    (2,33,'kkkkkkkkkkkk')
;


CREATE TABLE user
    (`user_id` int, `name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO user
    (`user_id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'John'),
    (2,'David'),
    (3,'Peter'),
    (4,'May')
;

CREATE TABLE product
    (`product_page_id` int, `name` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO product
    (`product_page_id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Sony A821'),
    (22,'Nokia 8234'),
    (444,'HTC 2811'),
    (777,'E821')

;
```

Here's my attempt ([Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc11d/10)):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT p.name AS product_page,poll.product_page_id,p2.name AS similar_product, 
         COUNT(poll.choice) As vote_result 
  FROM `poll` 
    INNER JOIN product p ON poll.product_page_id = p.product_page_id
    INNER JOIN `product` p2 ON poll.choice = p2.product_page_id  
  GROUP BY poll.choice
  ORDER By vote_result desc
)TAB1
JOIN
(
  SELECT pc.comment,pc.product_page_id,u.name 
  FROM `poll_comment` pc
   INNER JOIN `product` p ON pc.product_page_id = p.product_page_id
   INNER JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id = pc.user_id
  LIMIT 10
)TAB2
ON TAB1.product_page_id = TAB2.product_page_id
WHERE TAB1.product_page_id = 22
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `UNION`? - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach by using result of two querys and union all:

```
select PRODUCT_PAGE_ID,PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME,SIMILAR_PRODUCT,SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID,RESULT,null as VOTER_NAME , null as COMMENT from query1
UNION ALL
select PRODUCT_PAGE_ID,PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME,null as SIMILAR_PRODUCT,null as SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID,null as RESULT,VOTER_NAME,COMMENT from query2
```

Exact answer based on your data:

```
select PRODUCT_PAGE_ID,product_page as PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME,SIMILAR_PRODUCT,SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID,RESULT,null as VOTER_NAME , null as COMMENT from (SELECT p.product_page_id,p.name AS product_page,
       p2.name AS similar_product,
       p2.product_page_id AS similar_product_id,COUNT(poll.choice) AS result
FROM poll 
INNER JOIN product p ON poll.product_page_id = p.product_page_id
INNER JOIN product p2 ON poll.choice = p2.product_page_id
WHERE poll.product_page_id = 22
GROUP BY poll.choice
ORDER BY result DESC)temp

UNION ALL

select PRODUCT_PAGE_ID,PRODUCT_PAGE_NAME,null as SIMILAR_PRODUCT,null as SIMILAR_PRODUCT_ID,null as RESULT,VOTER_NAME,COMMENT from (SELECT pc.product_page_id,p.name AS product_page_name,
       u.name AS voter_name,pc.comment
FROM `poll_comment` pc INNER JOIN `user` u 
ON u.user_id = pc.user_id
INNER JOIN `product` p ON pc.product_page_id = p.product_page_id 
WHERE pc.product_page_id = 22)TEMP2
```